TypeOrm transaction is causing error: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block from PSQL
I've recently implemented transactional DB operations using the .transaction method.
Sample snippet would be here:
return entityManager.transaction(async (manager) => {
            await manager.save(PositionConfigurationEntity, currentConfiguration);

            await manager.delete(PositionConfigurationEntity, {
                positionId: positionConfiguration.positionId,
                recordType: PositionConfigurationRecordType.CURRENT,
            });

            const savedConfig = await manager.save(PositionConfigurationEntity, {
                ...currentConfiguration,
                ...positionConfiguration,
                id: undefined,
                recordType: PositionConfigurationRecordType.CURRENT,
                createdDate: undefined,
                isDeviatedFromDefaultConfig,
            });

            return savedConfig;
        });

But for some reason, I think this is causing an issue since other queries/ mutations will just randomly spew out:
{
"context": "ExceptionsHandler",
"level": "error",
"message": "current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block",
"stack": [
"QueryFailedError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block\n at QueryFailedError.TypeORMError [as constructor] (/odyssey/node_modules/typeorm/error/TypeORMError.js:9:28)\n at new QueryFailedError (/odyssey/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:13:28)\n at PostgresQueryRunner. (/odyssey/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:281:31)\n at step (/odyssey/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:144:27)\n at Object.throw (/odyssey/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:125:57)\n at rejected (/odyssey/node_modules/typeorm/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:116:69)\n at runMicrotasks ()\n at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)"
]
}

The snippet above is used in a mutation while the error is thrown from a query that is doing a totally different thing.
Please note that a lot of DB operations are being done in a matter of ms by different users so I'm not sure if that has an effect on it? Is it possible that the connection from these transactions are being used by other operations even though it hasn't finished its rollback yet?
Also, is the code enough to rollback on its own?
Haven't really done any code changes yet. The issue is intermittent so it's a bit hard to catch. Also, I think I need production level traffic to reproduce the error.

Did you find a solution ? We see the same issue from time to time, and we are wandering if this is a problem in typeorm or in our code ?

I did found the issue after debugging the DB logs and it and this has been fixed by typeorm: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/10210
From the logs, it seems that it's trying to restore from an incorrect savepoint.
what happened is that we're using another package, typeorm-cls-hooked and that's causing nested transactions to happen and trigger the error.
